# I am kind of stuck with this cipher

Tags: cipher

Someone recently sent me this cipher: (https://pastebin.com/uEg9dTpi), at first it's something that seems like decimal code and then there's an encrypted code that has a lot of letter repetitions, like an ADFGVX cipher, I don't know how to progress further. Do you guys have any idea what this is?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to decipher this by:

> doing a series of conversions of the data into different formats, mostly involving converting into and out of ASCII. The key to this method is to examine the output after each stage and determine what format it most resembles, in order to have a good guess as to what method to use to convert it further.

First,

> treat each number in the cipher text as a code for an ASCII character, and convert into the ASCII equivalent. That produces:

```
MDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAxMT;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAxMTAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMT;wMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMT;wMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAxMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAxMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAxMT;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAxMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMT;wMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMT;wMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAxMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMD;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAxMTAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAxMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAxMTAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMT;gMDAxMTAwMTAgMDAxMDAwMDAgMDAxMTAwMDAgMD;wMDAwMD;gMDAwMD;wMTAK
```

> This text resembles Base64 text, but when I tried to convert out of Base64 into other formats, the illegal semicolons gave me errors. On a hunch, noting that in ASCII the semicolon is decimal 059, whereas the uppercase E is 069 (off by one), I converted all the semicolons to E's. (The same result can be obtained by converting all instances of '59' in the original cipher text into '69'.) Then I did a Base64 to ASCII conversion on the resultant text, and got:

```
00110011 00110111 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110000 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110011 00100000 00110011 00110010 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110110 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00111001 00100000 00110011 00111000 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110100 00100000 00110011 00110100 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110011 00100000 00110011 00110010 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110010 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110111 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110011 00100000 00110011 00110010 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110101 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110000 00100000 00110011 00111000 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00111000 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110000 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110011 00100000 00110011 00110010 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110101 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110001 00100000 00110011 00110110 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110100 00100000 00110011 00110110 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110011 00100000 00110011 00110010 00100000 00110000 01000001 00001010
```

> This is 8-bit binary text. Converting from binary into ASCII text produces:
> 37 31 20 31 31 31 20 31 31 31 20 31 30 30 20 33 32 20 31 30 36 20 31 31 31 20 39 38 20 34 34 20 33 32 20 31 32 31 20 31 31 31 20 31 31 37 20 33 32 20 31 31 35 20 31 31 31 20 31 30 38 20 31 31 38 20 31 30 31 20 31 30 30 20 33 32 20 31 30 35 20 31 31 36 20 34 36 20 33 32 0A

Next,

> doing a hex to ASCII conversion produces:
> 71 111 111 100 32 106 111 98 44 32 121 111 117 32 115 111 108 118 101 100 32 105 116 46 32

Finally,

> doing a decimal to ASCII conversion produces

the answer:

> Good job, you solved it.